# Cannot access a closed Stream?

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader, memorystream

I have just come across an error in my code which opens up the file and reads the rawData.

The error I am getting is as follows:

[image]
As you can see, I am opening up a Memory Stream but as I do so I am getting an error saying that I cannot access the Stream?

I there a reason why I am not able to access a closed stream?

Code Used:

```
// Try to decompress the file data.
byte[] rawData = null;

using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream(fileData))
{
    if (ZipPackage.IsZipFile(zipStream))
    {
        using (ZipPackage unzipper = ZipPackage.Open(zipStream))
        {
            // The zip package only contains one entry since GeoObject.FileData only contains one shape or POI.
            if (unzipper.ZipPackageEntries.Count > 0)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(unzipper.ZipPackageEntries[0].OpenInputStream());
                rawData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stack

```
at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Position(Int64 value)
at Telerik.Windows.Zip.ZipPackage.IsZipFile(Stream stream)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.XmlConverters.DBGeoObjectsToFromDBShapes.ExtractRawFileData(GeoObject geoObject, Byte[] fileData)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.DatabaseShapesToFromMapShapes.ConvertDatabaseShapesToMapShapes(GeoObject geoObject, Boolean filter)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.DatabaseShapesToFromMapShapes.ConvertDatabaseShapesToMapShapes(GeoObject geoObject)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.ViewControllers.MainMapViewController.BackgroundWorkerFileLoad_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.<OnRun>b__1(Object state)
```

New Stack:

```
at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.Stream.CopyTo(Stream destination)
at Telerik.Windows.Zip.ZipArchive.WriteArchive()
at Telerik.Windows.Zip.ZipArchive.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at Telerik.Windows.Zip.ZipArchive.Dispose()
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.XmlConverters.DBGeoObjectsToFromDBShapes.ExtractRawFileData(GeoObject geoObject, Byte[] fileData)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.DatabaseShapesToFromMapShapes.ConvertDatabaseShapesToMapShapes(GeoObject geoObject, Boolean filter)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.DatabaseShapesToFromMapShapes.ConvertDatabaseShapesToMapShapes(GeoObject geoObject)
at Satmap.Planner.Silverlight.ViewControllers.MainMapViewController.BackgroundWorkerFileLoad_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.<OnRun>b__1(Object state)
```

Comment: Post short, executable code and the exception ToString output which contains the stack. Looks like a bug in the zip library.

Comment: @usr I have added the information. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: Looks like a bug, crash in internal code. Report to Telerik. They will want to see sample data, too, to reproduce.

Comment: Seems all rather unlikely.  Be careful with the debugger's Set Next Statement command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see here is the behavior of the Telerik `ZipPackage` class. The static `IsZipFile` method is disposing the stream, probably due to a bug (you may contact Telerik support about this).

However, it probably is not necessary that you first check the validity of the zip package. Simply use `try...catch` around the relevant pieces of code:

```
// Try to decompress the file data.
byte[] rawData = null;

using (MemoryStream zipStream = new MemoryStream(fileData))
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipPackage unzipper = ZipPackage.Open(zipStream))
        {
            // The zip package only contains one entry since GeoObject.FileData only contains one shape or POI.
            if (unzipper.ZipPackageEntries.Count > 0)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(unzipper.ZipPackageEntries[0].OpenInputStream());
                rawData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         // ZipPackage throws an exception of type Exception if the 
         // package is not valid. Handle exception here, e.g. log etc
    }
}
```

#### Update

Telerik's ZipArchive class seems a strange beast. If you are on .NET 4.5 or later, you might be better off switching to the `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` class. If not, you may be able to work around the problem with the non-expandable memory stream by not creating the memory stream from a fixed array. Instead of `new MemoryStream(fileData)` you can use:

```
using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    zipStream.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
    zipStream.Position = 0;

    // continue here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have just made that change and then the error `Memory stream is not expandable.` gets caught in the Exception?

Comment: @BenClarke: Can you update your question and post the new stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the update, everything works now. How come writing to the Stream works but passing as a parameter doesn't may i ask?

Comment: When you create a `MemoryStream` by passing in a byte array, the memory stream gets a fixed size and is unresizable. You *can* write to it, but you may not write more bytes than the initial size. If you just create a `MemoryStream` the internal buffer is not fixed-size and grow when you write to it. - Why the Telerik `ZipArchive` class wants to write to the stream although all you do is ask it to read the package I have absolutely no idea.